# truecrypt volume header store in safe place?

Tags: truecrypt

I am using truecrypt partition encryption and the docs say to backup the volume header in case the partition gets corrupted. Is this file suppose to be stored in a secure location or can anything be done with this file? Can I relax by storing a copy of this file unecrypted on a usb stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a question in the FAQs http://www.truecrypt.org/faq I would say that you want to keep it in a safe place.  it would allow people to essentially reset the password on an encrypted volume.

Comment: This is incorrect, you can't change the password without the original password, whether you have the volume header or not. You can never decrypt a TC volume without the correct password, which is NOT stored in the backup of a volume header.

Comment: deed02392 's answer should be the preferred answer.